# How to enqueue script based on post category?

Tags: shortcode, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have scripts for various little tools I have made using some js and html. I want the js to load only on specific single posts in side a specific category. I have tried the following code and it does not work. I removed the "if" statement and the script does run and work so it's a matter of fixing the if statement.

Here's what I've got so far,

```
    if ( is_single() && in_category( 'mouse' ) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousescript');
}
```

Thank you very much for any and all help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your theme's `functions.php` add something like this:

```
function my_conditional_enqueue_script() {
    global $post;
    if (is_single($post->ID) && in_category('mouse', $post->ID)) {
        wp_enqueue_script('mousescript');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_conditional_enqueue_script');
```

Also, make sure you use `wp_register_script` before you attempt to enqueue.

Comment: Hey @The Maniac, thanks for getting back to me! I tried that bit of code and no luck... I am inside my child themes function.php and yeah I have already registered the script - 'wp_register_script('mousescript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js');' if I just use 'wp_enqueue_script('mousescript');' after it it works. It only stops working after using an if statement.

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing this in a theme I'm currently developing and it worked for me. Seems obvious, but are you sure you have posts in the 'mouse' category? Are you sure the slug of that category is exactly `mouse`? Are you browsing to a single post (or page)?

Comment: excuse me you're absolutely correct. The slug was slightly incorrect and after fixing it, the script works perfectly. Thank you again, it works beautifully!