# Auto scroll to id on page load on all pages except home page. Only do this on mobile

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have a small UX issue where on mobile our header takes up a majority of the screen space. This causes confusion when you use our page links/navigation because there is no refresh visible above the fold.

To solve this we would like to auto scroll down to our #primary div on all pages except the home page. And I only wana do this on mobile devices. (screens less then 768px wide)

So far I can only apply it to all pages and it works on both desktop and mobile. I only want it to work on mobile and i want the home page to be ignored.

Here is code snippet im working with

```
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this work for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                        if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
                            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#primary").offset().top
        }, 2000);
                        } 
    });
```

Comment: This looks great as far as the mobile issue is concerned! How do i apply this to woocommerce product pages and categories only without editing woocommerce core files?

Comment: Or any page that is not the home page works too.

Comment: Thumbs up for now. Thnx!

Comment: then enque this script as your need. like this:  `function my_conditional_enqueue_script() {
    global $post;
    if (is_single($post->ID) && in_category('mouse', $post->ID)) {
        wp_enqueue_script('mousescript');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_conditional_enqueue_script');`   this   [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83849/how-to-enqueue-script-based-on-post-category)  may help you.